# Ansible jinja2 template with linux command

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am learning ansible. i have written a jinja2 template for looping over a multiple values. However, i get those values from a linux command.

```
- name: fetching port ranges 
  command: ls /apache |grep redis|grep ".pid"  | awk -F"_" '{ print $2}'| awk -F"." '{print $1}'
```

Output of the above command will be :

```
10001
10002
10003
10004
10005
```

Below is the jinja2 template

```
 [{% for range in port  %}
    "127.0.0.1:{{ range }}",
  {% endfor %}]
```

With "for loop" in the jinja2 template, i am trying iterate over the values generated by  linux command but i am not sure how to save those values and use it in jinja2 template. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the result and then use the output from `stdout_lines`.

Try something like this:

```
- name: fetching port ranges 
  command: ls /apache |grep redis|grep ".pid"  | awk -F"_" '{ print $2}'| awk -F"." '{print $1}'
  register: result

- name: my template task
  template:
    src: <src>
    dest: <dest>
  vars:
    port: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```